# Access a button in iframe, workaround same origin policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, same-origin-policy

Am trying this:

```
 $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('url') + '&callback=?', function(data){
 var siteContents = data.contents;
  $('.button class').trigger( "click" ).exec(siteContents);
});
```

I saw the 'exec' is if we want to match a string, but how to check the content of iframe to trigger a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a system where components are on a different origins, but you still control both of the sources, then you could use window.postMessage to communicate between the documents:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

If you don't control the source of the iframe, then you are out of luck. Allowing people to load whatever into their iframes and accessing the DOM  content of the loaded document is not allowed for good reasons.